# Using PyParsing to Distinguish Pattern at End of String

Tags: python, nlp, pyparsing

I am writing a script in python to identify and strip reference numbers from a natural text document. For instance, "The patient used a successful treatment4-6", where 4-6 are reference numbers.

I have successfully created a grammar that can distinguish a string of alphabet characters (the word) as well as the reference numbers:

```
real_word = Word(pyparsing.alphas)
first_punctuation = Word('.!?:,;')
second_punctuation = Word('.!?:,;-')
nums = Word(pyparsing.nums)

number_then_punctuation = WordStart() + real_word + nums + 
    second_punctuation + pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(nums | 
    second_punctuation) + WordEnd()
```

However, I would like to extend this to recognize words that might have dashes, or other characters in them. I think the easiest solution to this is to create a grammar to recognize the reference number pattern in a token, and then to strip it from the token (without caring about what the 'word' portion looks like), such that:

```
number_then_punctuation = nums + second_punctuation + 
    pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(nums | second_punctuation) + WordEnd()
```

However, this fails when I try to identify the pattern in the token using parseString, because there's no pattern for the word preceding the reference number. In a token, how can I skip to the reference number pattern, saving both the pattern as well as the preceding 'word' in a list? I can use searchString to find the pattern, but this doesn't save the preceding word.

In my above example, I would like to return ['treatment', '4-6']. I can do this using searchString, and then python's str.find() method:

```
string_test = 'treatment4-5'
x = number_then_punctuation.searchString(string_test).asList()[0][0]
index = string_test.find(x)
split = [string_test[:index], string_test[index:]]
```

But I'm hoping that there's a way to do this built in to pyparsing.

Thanks

Comment: I am not understanding your question. Why is `real_word + number_then_punctuation` not sufficient, if you expanded `real_word` to include commans and dashes? Even as-is, what you have would match "treatment4-6". There should be no confusion, unless you also include numbers in `real_word`, and even then this can be managed, albeit with some extra work.Perhaps you could post some examples of strings you  are trying to match, as well as some strings that you *don't* want to match.